# PHP regex question..adding commas

Tags: php

I have a list of values like this in a .txt file:

```
aaa
bbbb
ddd
eeeee
```

how would I append a comma and a space to the end of all of them so that the list looks like this

```
aaa, 
bbbb, 
ddd, 
eeeee,
```

thanks

Comment: Why bother with regex for this? Just read the file into a string line by line, append a comma and a space, and then write each line back out, in order.

Answer (score 4):

No need for regex. Just [get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) all the text from your file, do a good ol' [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [put](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)  it back in:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");
$contents = str_replace("\n", ",\n", $contents);
file_put_contents("myfile.txt", $contents);
```

This doesn't insert a comma if the last line does not have a newline, but if you really need it to be there, here's an improved version that deals with that:

```
$contents = trim(file_get_contents("myfile.txt"));
$contents = str_replace("\n", ",\n", $contents) . ",";
file_put_contents("myfile.txt", $contents);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
str_replace ( "\n", ",\n", $your_variable );
```

`str_replace` would be enought for your needs